# `The component does not have a resource identified by the URI` when assembly is in different folder

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, prism, assemblies

I am building a modular WPF app using Prism + Unity libraries. I split my solutions to following projects:
 - common project (interfaces)
 - main app, which loads dll
 - modules, they are NOT referenced by main app projects.

Submodules dlls are built to bin\(Debug|Release)\Modules folder

The code in main app to load is following:

It:

1. loads dlls from Modules folder
2. register types in DI container
3. setup modules from loaded dll (search for IModule types)

   ```
   protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog(IModuleCatalog moduleCatalog)
   {
       base.ConfigureModuleCatalog(moduleCatalog);

       List<Assembly> allAssemblies = new List<Assembly>();
       string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

       foreach (string dll in Directory.GetFiles(path + "/Modules/", "*.dll"))
           allAssemblies.Add(Assembly.LoadFile(dll));

       AutoRegisterClasses(allAssemblies);

       var modules = AllClasses.FromAssemblies(allAssemblies).Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IModule)));

       foreach (var module in modules)
       {
           moduleCatalog.AddModule(
               new ModuleInfo()
               {
                   ModuleName = module.Name,
                   ModuleType = module.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                   Ref = "file://" + module.Assembly.Location
               });
       }
   }

   private void AutoRegisterClasses(List<Assembly> allAssemblies)
   {
       var defaultRegisters = AllClasses.FromAssemblies(allAssemblies).Where(t => t.IsDefined(typeof(AutoRegisterAttribute), true));

       foreach (var register in defaultRegisters)         
           foreach (var interface_ in register.GetInterfaces()) 
               Container.GetContainer().RegisterType(interface_, register, null, new TransientLifetimeManager());
   }
   ```

Registration and module initialization works - everything is called. When I try to resolve **an interace from common project** which **is implemented in submodule project** I receive correct object. But when I try to display **ContentControl** which is returned by this provider I receive following exception:

> The component 'AdditionalDll.MainWindow' does not have a resource identified by the URI '/AdditionalDll;component/mainwindow.xaml'.

I have no idea why is it a problem, what is more interesting, when I do not store DLLs in Modules folder - that is, when I store them side by side with main exe, **everything works**!!!

I have created minimal solution which has this problem:
https://github.com/BAndysc/AssemblyLoadProblemExample

```
Common/Interfaces.cs - is common project, contains AutoRegister attribute and example interface that I will try to resolve
AdditionalDll/ExampleProvider.cs - is in submodule project, it is implementation of the mentioned interface, it returns new view from AdditionalDll project
TestMultiProjectApp/App.xaml.cs - setups everything - load dlls, register types, init modules
TestMultiProjectApp/MainWindow.xaml - is simple view, which shows given ContentControl
TestMultiProjectApp/MainWindowViewModel.cs - is simple viewmodel, which resolves IProvider interface (it works) and on command assigns returned view to property, which is then displayed by view (this causes exception)
```

While keeping dlls in same folder as exe is some workaround, I would rather keep them in separate folder to keep things tidy, if anyone has an idea how to fix them, I will appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

This is flawed on so many levels. For instance:

- the module isn't found by the module catalog
- the application wants to manually load the types in the modules
- the `MainWindowViewModel` tries to create and store a `ContentControl`
- naming - why are there two `MainWindow`s?

You should take a step back and revisit your architecture. What are the responsibilities of your modules? What's the responsibility of your application? How do you want to identify and load the modules?  How do you want to deploy and load the dependencies of the modules? How's the planned layout of your gui?

And you should take another step back and revisit some basic documentation about WPF development, namely data binding, data templates, resource dictionaries, the difference between view and view model.

Edit: let me address some points mentioned in the comments.

- the very raison d'être of a module is that it registers its own stuff. So yes, it is bad if someone else does that for the module, because you take away all things the module brings in in the first place. In fact, I'd argue that a module shouldn't even expose any `public` types.
- the view model's properties are either built in types or other view models. The mapping between view and view model happens through `DataTemplate`s or (in case of Prism) through the `ViewModelLocator`. Never ever should a view model own, create or know a view type if you can help it.
- There's nothing wrong with registration by convention per se, but limit yourself to the module at hand. The application may register the types known to the app, but the types in the modules should be registered by the modules.
- Prism provides a way of creating dependencies between modules to define a partial ordering used when loading the modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but:

`> the module isn't found by the module catalog`

Yes it is, I look for loaded IModule types and load them to catalog
`> the application wants to manually load the types in the modules`
is that really bad? Reduces a lot of boilerplate code
`> the MainWindowViewModel tries to create and store a ContentControl`
why is that bad? What is other way to pass some view from other module to main app?
`> naming - why are there two MainWindows?`
This is only minimal example which shows the error, I have quickly added new window, changed it to UserControl,

Comment: Again, that's only small example which shows the problem, but I don't see big flaws in the architecture. Each module provides separate functionality. For example in my real app, Common project contains an interface IDatabaseProvider, for database access, other project implements it (actually I have two implementations for this already), of course only one implementation can be active at one time, so during loading, main app can detect this (two modules implement same Unique Interface) and disable one. I don't see how could I do this if I loaded every dll and in that dll I would register types.

Comment: `How do you want to deploy and load the dependencies of the modules?` With this architecture it is also easy, project which requires database access would just have attribute on its module `[RequiresInterface(typeof(IDatabaseProvider))]` and during loading that module I can detect that no module provides that functionality.

Comment: `the difference between view and view model` I am not sure what you mean, app view in my main app just shows some view from other project. It doesn't matter which now. And this is ViewModel to provide what it should show, isn't it? Why view should bother with it? View is responsible for *how* to display it, viewmodel for *what* to display.